# I get dependency issues with linux-image-pae while upgrading

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, dependencies

```
$ sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-generic-pae
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,578 B of archives. After unpacking 1,024 B will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic-pae
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic-pae
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` along with `sudo apt-get install -f`. None of these have fixed my issue.

Comment: You should read [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/62483) and try with some of the answers there.

Answer (score 1):

`linux-image-generic-pae` is a transitional package, which means it doesn't exist anymore in the repos since `linux-image-generic` includes the pae funcionality.

I would remove it, making sure you have the real package installed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

If it's already installed, just in case:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic-pae
```